# SQL Server Job Documenting and Scheduling

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm looking for a tool or low-overhead way to automatically document scheduled SQL agent jobs across about 20 MS SQL 2005 servers. There are various jobs which run periodically as well as nightly backups; during the day the servers are accessible to users for manual queries.

Basically, everything is bumping into everything else. Ideally, I'd like to find some kind of tool which looks at all the scheduling data across all the severs and generates a calendar based report. I'm wondering if anyone has seen anything like this? I've got the RedGate suite, and their SQLDoc tool doesn't seem to do this in a particularly useful way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check out SQL Sentry's Event Manager:

http://sqlsentry.com/event-manager/sql-server-job-scheduler-enterprise.asp

I don't work for them - I actually work for a competitor - but it's a really nice product from what I've seen, and I've heard good things from other users.

Comment: SQLSentry is the best tool for this if you can get the budget. They resell this tool to Idera.

Answer (score 0):

first shot, try IDERA, they have a free tool called Job Manager that is a lite version of a paid product - it only allows connection to max of 20 servers. [www.idera.com](http://www.idera.com/Products/Free-Tools/SQL-job-manager/). It allows editing of job properties and drag and drop schedule changes. The interface is simple and gives a really good snapshot of your job execution history with the option to drill in to get error details.

We have [RedGate SQL Response](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Response/index.htm) as our main SQL Server health monitor. Its got a free 14 day trial option.

I'm sure there are more that are just as good but I have not experienced any of the current version from other providers

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, from SQL Mag - Creating a Job Scheduling Advisor.

http://www.sqlmag.com/Article/ArticleID/100664/sql_server_100664.html